# How do I wire up Castle Windsor in a Web Forms Web Site Project

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container

I'm trying to introduce dependency injection into an existing Web Forms application.  The project was created as a Web Site project (as opposed to a Web Application Project).  I have seen samples where you create your global class in global.asax.cs and it looks something like this:

```
public class GlobalApplication : HttpApplication, IContainerAccessor
{
    private static IWindsorContainer container;

    public IWindsorContainer Container
    {
        get { return container; }
    }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            container = <...>
        }
    }
```

But in a web site project, if you ask to add a global class, it adds only global.asax which contains a server-side script tag:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup

}
```

There doesn't seem to be a way for me to derive from HttpApplication (and IContainerAccessor) here.  Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5):

I found a way.  The global.asax file should only contain:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" Inherits="GlobalApp"  %>
```

then in the app_code folder I created GlobalApp.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using Castle.Windsor;

public class GlobalApp : HttpApplication, IContainerAccessor
{
    private static IWindsorContainer _container;
    private static IWindsorContainer Container {
        get
        {
            if (_container == null)
                throw new Exception("The container is the global application object is NULL?");
            return _container;
        }
    }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        if (_container == null) {
            _container = LitPortal.Ioc.ContainerBuilder.Build();
        }
    }

    IWindsorContainer IContainerAccessor.Container
    {
        get {
            return Container;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems important to make `_container` static.  I found that objects of the GlobalApp class were being created multiple times.  The Application_Start method is only being called the first time.  When I had `_container` as a non-static field, it was null for the second and subsequent instantiations of the class.

To make referencing the container easy in other portions of the code, I defined a helper class Ioc.cs

```
using System.Web;
using Castle.Windsor;

public static class Ioc
{
    public static IWindsorContainer Container {
        get {
            IContainerAccessor containerAccessor = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance as IContainerAccessor;
            return containerAccessor.Container;
        }
    }
}
```

That way, other portions of the code, should they need to access the container can use `Ioc.Container.Resolve()`

Does this sound like the correct setup?